# Python: how to refer to an instance name?

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm collecting instances using the following code:

```
class Hand():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):
        Hand.instances.append(self)
        self.value = 5

    def do_something(self, a):
        self.value = self.value * a

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def insty(self):
        self.hand1 = Hand()
        self.hand2 = Hand()


foo = Foo()
foo.insty()
print Hand.instances

for hand in Hand.instances:
    print "how do I print the instance name?"
```

The last line is just a way to learn how to to access the instance name so i can call the 'do_something' method on each instance in order.

How do I access the instance name for each instance of Hand?

Comment: What do you mean by "instance name"?  What do you think the "name" of each instance is?

Comment: "hand1" and "hand2" is what i'm referring to... perhaps erroneously.  I'm a newbie... be gentle!

Comment: What's wrong with `for hand in Hand.instances: hand.do_something()` ?

Comment: @dwstein instance name is just a variable pointing to an object, 
for eg if you've , `foo=Foo()`, and then `foo1=foo`, then both `foo` and `foo1` point to `Foo()`, how will you name the instance then?

Comment: So I met this person the other day... how come I wasn't able to determine his name, just by looking at him? And what do you *mean* people sometimes have more than one name?

Comment: @qiao Thanks!  You've solved my problem and I see there's no real need to access the variable names 'hand1' or 'hand2'.

Comment: ...why on earth has this question been upvoted 3 times?

Comment: @ErikAllik If you're asking me, I think its important for other newbie knuckle-heads like me to see answers to dumb questions.  Many of the tutorials on line and much of the documentation are heavy on theory and light on examples.  The answers here leave me understanding this concept in no uncertain terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean how to get `hand1` from the instance you assigned to `self.hand1`, the answer is that you can't.  When you do `self.hand1 = Hand()`, you tell the Foo object it has a Hand, but the Hand object has no knowledge that it has been assigned to a Foo.  You could do this:

```
h = Hand()
self.bob = h
self.larry = h
```

Now what is the "name" of that Hand supposed to be?  You assigned the same hand to both "bob" and "larry", so there's no way it can have a single unique name.

If you want to have a name for each hand, you need to tell the hand what name you want to give it.  You would have to modify your Hand code to allow you to pass a name to the constructor, then create the Hand with `Hand("some name")`.

You can of course give the hands "names" by assigning attributes on them:

```
self.hand1 = Hand()
self.hand1.name = "hand 1"
```

. . . but these names are not special or "automatic" in any way.

The bottom line is that if you want something to have a name, *you* need to decide how to handle that name.  You need write your own code that gives it its name, and your own code that retrieves its name.

Answer (score 1):

`foo = Foo()` means that the variable `foo` just points to the object returned by `Foo()`, there's no concept of name here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would solve your problem or not. I needed to get instance names in order to do clear error reporting. Everywhere I looked, folks said "variables don't have names! The name is just a pointer to the thing!"

But it turns out that getting instance names in python is pretty straightforward. 
Here's how I did it:

```
import gc
def instance_names(self):
    referrers = gc.get_referrers(self)
    result = []
    dict_of_things = {}
    for item in referrers:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            dict_of_things = item
    for k, v in dict_of_things.items():
        if v == self:
            result.append(k)
    if not result:
        result = ['unnamed instance']
    return result
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. However, links tend to get broken overtime. Could you maybe add relevant parts of your code as well? Thanks.

Comment: @imzcig, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

`foo.__dict__` will have "`hand1`" and "`hand2`" keys (among others).  But you're probably going about this the wrong way.  If the names are significant, you should use them as explicit indices in `Foo` (or somewhere).

e.g.

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hands = {}

    def insty(self):
        self.hands['hand1'] = Hand()
        self.hands['hand2'] = Hand()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Will this work if I'm creating instances dynamically?  i.e. I won't know how many instances are being created,

Comment: Yes, but you should try to read more information about the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) type.

Comment: You should forget that `__dict__` exists. It is an implementation detail, and isn't meant to be poked.

Comment: Indeed, but it's likely one of very few answers to OP's original question.